# Why we write probabilities int % and not out of 1

Tags: probability

I always wondered why we write probabilities in % instead of out of 1 when out of 1 is more logical, for example if you are not familiar with percentages a 50% chance sounds like nothing but 1/2 sounds more logical since it says that is half possible. Also when you multiply probabilities one another you need to put them out of one. So why use percentage when out of one is more logical and practical?

Comment: Arbitrary historical usage preserved in the present and ensconced in literature such that it is unlikely ever to change...

Comment: I think using percentages is only more common in popular parlance.  In mathematics, using fractional or decimal values between $0$ and $1$ is more common—by a significant margin, I believe.

Comment: One possible advantage is the percentages make it clear that you are talking about a proportion rather than some other unit. If a teacher wrote $0.75$ on a test, then it's not exactly clear if that means you got $3/4$ of questions right or you have $0.75$ points out of $2$ or $3$ or whatever. However $75$% is less ambiguous. Another possible advantage might be that it's easier to parse. Consider $245/398$ versus $61.5$%. You get a better sense of what the proportion is with the latter case.

Comment: It's neither arbitrary, nor simply historical/popular. The whole concept of "probability" is very tricky and the absolute majority of probabilities you encounter outside of theoretical math/physics are based on a concept of PROPORTION with a vague "select one at random" added on to translate it into PROBABILITY. Proportions are conveniently reported in %, so probabilities are reported in % as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is: we're stuck with the convention due to historical habit.

Mathematicians understand that writing $50\%$ is just a particular way of expressing the probability $1/2$ - but that point of view is a relatively modern one. Probability didn't emerge as a field of study until a few centuries ago (around the Renaissance).

Expressing fractions of a whole as hundredths, on the other hand, dates back to Roman times ([source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percentage)):

> In Ancient Rome, long before the existence of the decimal system, computations were often made in fractions which were multiples of 1⁄100. For example, Augustus levied a tax of 1⁄100 on goods sold at auction known as centesima rerum venalium. Computation with these fractions was similar to computing percentages. As denominations of money grew in the Middle Ages, computations with a denominator of 100 became more standard and from the late 15th century to the early 16th century it became common for arithmetic texts to include such computations. Many of these texts applied these methods to profit and loss, interest rates, and the Rule of Three. By the 17th century it was standard to quote interest rates in hundredths.

Thus, by the time mathematicians came to understand probabilities as fractions of a whole, there was already a millennia-old standard in place of using hundredths to express such a concept. Not the most elegant way of doing things, but the sciences are littered with examples of conventions that didn't turn out to be the most efficient. Plenty of engineers wish Ben Franklin had defined positive and negative charge the opposite way, for example.

Also worth noting is that when mathematicians talk about probabilities, they usually *do* use fractions of $1$ rather than $100$ for reasons that include the ones you mention in your question. It's in areas where those concerns don't matter as much (such as saying there's a 40% chance of rain today) you're far more likely to see historical convention dominate because there's not as much value gained from being able to work with those numbers mathematically.

Answer (score 2):

That is convenction. % are much more easy to read.

Compare: `0.015` vs `1.5 %`. For smaller fractions `ppm` or even `ppb` is used.

Comment: Well... It depends on the context. I don't recall seeing a lot of $\permill$ in the last propability course I attended.

Comment: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parts_per_million I am electronic developer and `ppm` is used almost everywhere for expressing values between 10^-6 to 10^-3, `ppb` for <10^-6 etc.

Comment: Well, for instance, [ppm is not accepted in SI](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=parts+per+million).

Comment: Good catch, upvoted. In electronics the "part per something" is almost exclusively used for expresing some relative instabilities or drifts. In chemistry for inpurities or small concentrations amounts. Something like for gold, you also almost never say 0.9999 purity. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Q: "How many students passed the test?"

A1: "0.94 of them."
A2: "94% of them."

Call me crazy but "94%" sounds clearer (and *is* clearer if we replaced "student" with something divisible down to the hundredth).

Of course, % = "percent" = "per cent" = "per hundredth." You could answer "ninety-four out of one hundred students passed the test," or you could say 94%, which, as a matter of common English, won't imply there are exactly 100 students, while "out of one hundred" opens up that ambiguity.

You could also say "0.94 out of every 1 student passed," but it sounds very confusing to invoke 0.94 of one student when a student is not divisible. Gender neutrality notwithstanding I imagine you would need to say "For every student, 0.94 of her passed," since "1" is of course singular and requires a singular pronoun. The listener could be forgiven for wondering what part of the one student failed.

I really think it's this simple and that it has a lot more to do with common usage than mathematical rigor and elegance.